# Create product with Shopify Admin API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

I've started working with React and Node.js for the first time, on building an private Shopify App. The app's purpose is to listen to an add to cart button, when clicked it should create a custom product in the Shopify Backend with the Shopify Product API. I've worked plenty in basic JavaScript and have great experience in jQuery, to handle the more basics of this project. The tought part is binding the POST event to the add to cart click, creating the product and adding it to the cart.

I'm trying the following solution for creating the product in the backend. Is this the correct way of doing it, or is there a better solution for doing this?

How can i bind this Fetch function to an click event?

```
    let new_product = {
        product: {
            title: Custom,
            body_html: test,
            vendor: Custom,
            product_type: customproduct,
            tags: Customproduct
        }
    };


fetch('/admin/api/2020-07/products.json', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(new_product),

  headers: {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },

})
```

I'm using Isomorphic Fetch in my project, which should work server and client side.

Any help and guidance would be appreciately recieved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You have got several questions there. Before answering, it is important to clear few misconceptions that I assumed from your wording and sample code. There are 3 types of [Shopify Apps](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps).

1. Public
2. Custom
3. Private

So if you are building a Private app, then provided code will not work for creating Product because Private apps use Basic authentication while Public and Custom apps manage authentication with OAuth 2.0.

> I'm using Isomorphic Fetch in my project, which should work server and
> client side.

Even though it works on Server and Client ends, do not call Shopify API from Client side as this will expose your private app credentials.

To implement what you are trying to do, you need to modify React App as well as Backend code.

1. Add an event listener to Button
2. Send a POST request to Backend server
3. Create Product on Shopify via API
4. Add the product to cart using ID returned in previous step
5. Return the Cart URL in response

Sample code in React would look like

```
function Product() {
  const addProduct = async () => {
    const cart = await fetch("/your-end-point", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // add product params
      }),
    });
  };

  return <button onClick={addProduct}>Add Product</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Product />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then inside your Node.js application, handle the Shopify API part. Instead of using fetch, I will recommend using [Official Node.js module for Shopify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node).

Sample code will look like

```
const Shopify = require("shopify-api-node");
router.post("/your-end-point", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const shopify = new Shopify({
      shopName: "your-shop-name",
      apiKey: "your-api-key",
      password: "your-app-password",
    });
    const product = await shopify.product.create(req.body);
    // use product ID from previous request
    const checkout = await shopify.checkout.create({
      /*checkout params */
    });
    res.status(200).send(checkout);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
});
```

Comment: HI @Bilal Akbar

Thank you for your great response. It has been helpfull, and definitely clarified most of questions regarding this. Thank you. 

I can see that you are using route, which returns: ReferenceError: router is not defined

When searching around for router, i keep seying people referring to App Proxies. Is this something we need to implement for this functionality?

Comment: This route was from Express framework. This was just an example. This is not a drop in code that will work for you. Implement the route listener in your Node.js app using whatever framework you are using. And App Proxies are for rendering your pages inside Shopify client store. You don't need that.

Comment: I see. I used Koa for this projected, and now installe a Koa router middleware. No errors. I was wondering about the const checkout part. Which parametres are required here, and what is the main purpose of this? Is this parametres needed for the add to cart functionality?

I suppose the const cart in the react module, would post to the shopify cart api?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Bilal Akbar, Thank you again. I have an additional follow up question, as I'm struggling to understand how it works exactly. I have an index.js and _app.js for extending - for the embedded part of the app (in this case it's not embedded as it's a Private App). I have installed the app and tried to make a simple logging function and then creating a button in my template, with an onclick calling that function. It says the function doesn't exist. How come?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard I am not sure if I understood your question. Kindly ask a new question with relevant information so that anyone can answer. Moreover, I don't have any experience with Embedded apps.

Comment: Hi Birbal, I am building a public app for Shopify so can you please tell me how to access admin API with authentication? Do I need to use X-Shopify-Access-Token on server side? And there is a mention on sending session token like Authorization: Bearer <session_token> from client side to server side, So can you please help me  out how to use it?