# How to make requests to Shopify's GraphQL Admin API with Vue & Apollo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I'm struggling to make requests to Shopify's GraphQL Admin API from my Vue app with the following setup:

*src/lib/apolloClient.js*

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json",
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  headers: {
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "{password}",
  },
  cache,
});

export default apolloClient;
```

*src/main.js*

```
import { createApp, provide, h } from "vue";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
import App from "./App.vue";
import apolloClient from "./lib/apolloClient";

createApp({
  setup() {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient);
  },
  render: () => h(App),
}).mount("#app");
```

I've been getting a CORS preflight error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

And when adding

```
fetchOptions: {
  mode: 'no-cors'
}
```

to my ApolloClient initialisation I get the following error:

```
unexpected end of JSON
```

I'm not too sure if my setup is completely not ideal or if I'm just missing a few configs.

I'm very new to Shopify Dev, but I'd like to build some extended functionality into my product listing pages with JavaScript. If anyone has got some experience with this, I'd appreciate some advice on how I should be architecting this, I'm not at all opposed to taking a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design, you aren't supposed to hit the Admin API on the front-end due to the security reasons, mainly due to the fact that you'd need to embed auth keys in your front-end bundle and that's always prone to disastrous effects.

You'll need to route those requests to a backend app of your own and that'll consume the API and proxy it to your front-end through [App Proxies](https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies)

See also:

[Create product with Shopify Admin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904556/create-product-with-shopify-admin-api)

[Can we get product by SKU using Shopify Storefront GraphQL API(NOT ADMIN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412693/can-we-get-product-by-sku-using-shopify-storefront-graphql-apinot-admin)

[is that possible to use admin APIs in frontend directly in the store without app](http://%20%20https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/is-that-possible-to-use-admin-apis-in-frontend-directly-in-the/td-p/614887)